# how to find a record where you have to check inside a json object in an array field using postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to select * programs which are today and they should have the same schedule or nothing. Each program has a session array with json objects, each json object has a start_time, a finish_time (like this 11:00:44) and a day ( ex. Monday).
I want to select the program which has a session object that has a day as currentDay and the currenttime between the start_time + programs.entry_time_range (which is 30 ) and start_time-programs.entry_time_range.

I write this query:

```
SELECT *
      FROM programs
      WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM json_array_elements(sessions)  AS session
          WHERE
            session->>'day' = :day 
            AND :currentDate::time BETWEEN (session->>'start_time'::time - (entry_time_range || ' minutes')::interval)::time
            AND (session->>'start_time'::time + (entry_time_range || ' minutes')::interval)::time
        )
             
      AND( filter IS NULL
          OR filter LIKE :schedule
        )
      AND :currentDate BETWEEN startline AND deadline       
      AND facility_id = :facility_id;`
```

but I cannot make it work, I got this error:

```
function json_array_elements(json[]) does not exist
```

I tried to cast to json object too but I got another error.

So how can I solve this? What should I do??

Here an example program table:

```
id | start_line | deadline | filters | facility_id | entry_time_range | sessions
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | 2023-04-03 03:00:00+03 | 2023-04-03 03:00:00+03 | {"in":[{"schedule":[["de682021-c99a-47a5-bc3a-8e089e033732"]]}]} | 'some_id' | 30 | {"{\"day\":\"Monday\",\"start_time\":\"06:00:00\",\"finish_time\":\"07:00:00\"}","{\"day\":\"Thursday\",\"start_time\":\"16:11:00\",\"finish_time\":\"23:00:00\"}"}
```

Comment: This fails because `json[]` is a Postgres array of JSON elements and `json_array_elements()` is for JSON type array. The docs are there for a reason  read [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) and [ARRAY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) and the corresponding function sections from here [Functions/operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html). FYI, you don't want to mix types.

Comment: thanks I used unnest, I thought json[] and json type array were the same.

Comment: You would be better off long term changing that field to `json(b)` and converting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my answer in case other would need.
I could access to the json objects inside the array using unnest as following:

```
 SELECT *
        FROM programs
        WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM unnest(sessions) AS session
          WHERE session->>'day' = :day 
            AND :currentDate::time BETWEEN 
                ((session->>'start_time')::time - (entry_time_range || ' minutes')::interval)::time
                AND ((session->>'start_time')::time + (entry_time_range || ' minutes')::interval)::time
        )              
        AND (filter IS NULL OR filter LIKE :schedule)
        AND :currentDate BETWEEN startline AND deadline       
        AND facility_id = :facility_id;
```